# ruby appium driver tap gesture does not work

Tags: android, ruby, selenium, appium, gestures

Setup

- ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
- appium_lib (9.4.9)
- selenium-webdriver (3.4.0)
- touch_action (1.3.3)
- watir (6.3.0)
- Selenium Standalone server v3.4.0
- appium-desktop-Setup-1.1.0-beta.4
- Nexus 5 phone is connected to the PC via USB Appium server registers as a node to selenium-grid node (that all works fine)

Wanted action/step to perform

- I want to perform a tap on an element (instead of a click)
- While using selenium-webdriver version >=3.4.0

IRB

```
require 'appium_lib'
require 'touch_action'
grid_url = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" 
capabilities = {
'browserName' => 'chrome',
'platformName' => 'Android',
'deviceName' => 'Nexus5',
'newCommandTimeout' => '15000',
'javascript_enabled' => true 
}
browser = Appium::Driver.new(caps: capabilities, url: grid_url).start_driver
browser.get("https://www.google.nl")
sleep 5
inputfield = browser.find_element(:id, 'lst-ib')
inputfield.click
inputfield.send_keys("appium mobile gestures ruby")
sleep 2
button = browser.find_element(:id, 'tsbb')
```

So far so good.
But when I try to perform a tab action. it fails

```
irb(main):026:0> button.touch_action(:tap)
NoMethodError: undefined method `executeScript' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::OSS::Bridge:0x3119b50>
from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/touch_action-1.3.3/lib/touch_action/selenium-webdriver.rb:9:in `touch_action'
from (irb):26
from C:/Ruby23/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

I have the feeling I miss something small a detail (I'm new to appium), I just don't see the mistake I make here.
So if someone can point me in the right direction that would be really helpful.
For example scrolling also did not do anything for me (just returned nil)
https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

I also tried some other commands that I found here:
https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/appium-bindings.md

For example driver.lock (in my case browser.lock), worked so I can interact with the phone commands. It just looks like I can't do anything with the website besides finding elements, .get and .click (I was also not able to scroll to an element or scroll down).

I even tried this on the https://hammerjs.github.io website to be sure there was an element that tab being suppose to be responding to touch events (the id hitarea), same result.

Comment: I noticed that when I used the appium_lib gem version 8.0.3 I did not get the error anymore, yet I was still not able to swipe,tab (nothing happened) So I'm still missing something in my configuration I guess. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Touch_action most likely does no work with a newer version of selenium-webdriver (executeScript v/s execute_script).
 I had contact with the developer of the touch_action gem and he asked me to use a lower version of selenium-webdriver. Which I tried, but the result is the same as mentioned in my previous comment. No error appears, but I also do not see the tap/swipe. Here is a link to an example I recorded https://1drv.ms/v/s!AiGFi7A5PO9Uhacq5Wv056uCTZp9uw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe my initial question was not really clear, but I really had no clue what I exaclty was looking for either (not that many examples about ruby + appium + touch action in combination with tests on Android + Chrome)

So I tried the touch_action ruby gem. Unfortunatelly this was not what I was looking for. Maybe I'm doing something basic wrong, but I could not get it to work with the latest watir and selenium-webdriver.

Then I tried appium_lib which gave me a bit of a headacke since I saw so many examples (even some good ruby ones), but again I did exactly the same and it did not seem to work on my machine. The problem with my setup was that the driver was in the CHROMIUM context and Appium::TouchAction .perform can only be done in the NATIVE_APP context.
https://discuss.appium.io/t/ruby-appium-touchaction-perform-returns-error-method-has-not-yet-been-implemented/18308
So keep that in mind when using the appium/android driver and you want to use the TouchAction events.